# A cobweb is "durable" or "stringy"?

Tags: adjectives

What defines best the cobwebs ability to withstand weight/pressure/force?

Comment: High tensile strength.

Comment: And a shock-absorbing mechanism

Answer (score 4):

In engineering terms it is strong (has a high tensile strength as iMerchant said), it is also robust (not brittle and resists shock loads).

It isn't durable (normally means it resists abrasion) and is only *stringy* in that it is made of thread

Comment: Yeah, I would say *robust*, *sturdy*, *stout*, or *tough*.